# Find index of closing bracket in string list

Tags: c#

I am getting input from a text file. I have read all the text and tokenized it.

Here is input sample

```
.MAIN [
    .HEADING1 [ .TEXT 30000 ]
    .HEADING2 [
      [
        .TEXT1 YAMA
        .TEXT2 THAH
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

After tokenization, tokens list contains ".MAIN", "[", ".HEADING1", and so on. Now what I want to find index of closing bracket for a particular starting square bracket. For example if i give my function index 0 (the first starting square bracket) function should return me last index, and if give my function index of starting square bracket of .HEADING1 then it should return me index of closing bracket at same line.

Comment: Transform your list into a tree structure. Every open bracket is a new node.

Comment: Not really answerable without an idea of (the result of) your tokenizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
        //Give it index of first bracket you want
        int myStartingIndex = 0;
        string s = "[ sfafa sf [fasfasfas ] [ test ] ]";
        int firstClosedIndex = s.IndexOf("]", myStartingIndex + 1);
        int firstOpenedIndex = s.IndexOf("[", myStartingIndex + 1);
        while (firstOpenedIndex < firstClosedIndex)
        {
            firstClosedIndex = s.IndexOf("]", firstClosedIndex + 1);
            firstOpenedIndex = s.IndexOf("[", firstOpenedIndex + 1);

            //Break if there is no any opened bracket
            //index before closing index
            if (firstOpenedIndex == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Required index is {0}", firstClosedIndex);
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for index of a flat string list of tokens, rather than the index within a single string.

Comment: Yes it's not made particularly clear in the original question.

Comment: this will work, but this is a little bit complex, answer of @HollyStyles is simple and i am going with that.

Comment: hey, you should accept HollyStyles's answer if it worked better :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = 3;
int bracketCount = 1;

for(int i = index + 1; i < tokenlist.Count; i++)
{
    if(tokenList[i] == "]")
    {
        bracketCount--;
    }
    if(tokenList[i] == "[")
    {
        bracketCount++;
    }
    if(bracketCount == 0)
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a stack to push open bracket "[" and Pop at "]" close bracket.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int FindClosingBracketIndex(string text, char openedBracket = '{', char closedBracket = '}')
        {
            int index = text.IndexOf(openedBracket);
            int bracketCount = 1;
            var textArray = text.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = index + 1; i < textArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (textArray[i] == openedBracket)
                {
                    bracketCount++;
                }
                else if (textArray[i] == closedBracket)
                {
                    bracketCount--;
                }

                if (bracketCount == 0)
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }
```